# How to create a pop-up window that's independent of modal windows (.NET Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, popupwindow

I'm trying to implement a 'step-by-step guide' feature in my Windows Forms application.  The guides are just step-by-step descriptions of how to do common tasks.  I'm intending for users to work through the instructions while reading the guides.  The window in which they're displayed therefore needs to be **accessible when modal dialogs are being displayed**.

Is this possible?  If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Do you mean like tooltips that point to the respective controls? Yes, this is possible; just create windows owned by the window in question. A UI-modal dialog is just a dialog that disables its owner and a code-modal dialog just runs its own message pump; read Raymond Chen's series on dialogs for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for andLabs, Tim and IInspectable for giving me the information I needed to solve the problem.  The following does what I needed:

```
Thread myFormThread = new Thread(delegate()
{
    Application.Run(new MyForm());
});
myFormThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
myFormThread.Start();
```

It works fine.  Obviously you need to be careful to use myForm.BeginInvoke if you need to access the controls on myForm from an event-handler of the main form.  You also need to help the user to manage access to the form as it can get lost behind other windows.

Answer (score 0):

When a modal is displayed, you cannot interact with any other windows in the same UI thread.  It is possible (but probably not the best idea in the world) to run two distinct UI threads in the same process in C#-- but you will have to be very careful to keep things stable.  In the main thread, run your normal modal form.  In the secondary thread, you can run a non-modal form at the same time-- just keep a dedicate windows message pump running in that thread until you are done with the UI, and then shut down the message pump and exit the thread.

Comment: Modality is implemented by disabling the owner window. A thread can have any number of windows, with only one window being disabled, that owns the modal dialog. There is nothing built into the system, that disables all windows on a thread. Besides, having more than one UI thread is not at all challenging, so long as you do not install any cross-thread window hierarchies (owner/owned or child/parent).